# Finding source code of Visual Studio standard library function marked Extern C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, std

I'm currently trying to find the Visual Studio implementation of the [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/laguerre) `std::laguerre` from the header `<cmath>`.

I followed the following steps:

1. I opened a `.h` file window in Visual Studio.
2. I added the following lines of code:

```
#include <cmath>

double a = std::laguerre(1, 2);
```

3. I highlighted `std::laguerre` and clicked "Go to Definition."
4. I then double clicked the line that ends in `\include\cmath` from the long list that appeared.
5. I then <kbd>**ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**f**</kbd>-ed " laguerre(" and found this code:

```
// FUNCTION laguerre
_NODISCARD inline double laguerre(const unsigned int _Arg1, const double _Arg2) {
    return __std_smf_laguerre(_Arg1, _Arg2);
}
```

between lines 1186 and 1189. This is almost what I want, but I need more implementation details. I need to know how `__std_smf_laguerre` is implemented.

6. I then <kbd>**ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**f**</kbd>-ed `__std_smf_laguerre` and found this section of code:

```
#if _HAS_CXX17
_EXTERN_C
_NODISCARD _CRT_SATELLITE_2 double __stdcall __std_smf_assoc_laguerre(unsigned int, unsigned int, double) noexcept;
...

_NODISCARD _CRT_SATELLITE_2 float __stdcall __std_smf_hermitef(unsigned int, float) noexcept;
_NODISCARD _CRT_SATELLITE_2 double __stdcall __std_smf_laguerre(unsigned int, double) noexcept;
_NODISCARD _CRT_SATELLITE_2 float __stdcall __std_smf_laguerref(unsigned int, float) noexcept;
...

_NODISCARD _CRT_SATELLITE_2 float __stdcall __std_smf_hypot3f(float, float, float) noexcept;
_END_EXTERN_C
```

It appears to me that the function I want to view has been marked `EXTERN_C`. I understand that this should tell the linker that it can find the definition of `__std_smf_laguerre` *somewhere*.

How should I proceed to find the definition of `__std_smf_laguerre`?

Comment: I'm more interested in *why* you need to know the specific implementation of this function? What is the actual underlying problem you need to solve by finding the implementation? What makes you think that knowing the implementation will help solve that problem? And does it have to be this specific implementation? I'll bet if you search a little you can find many other implementations, maybe not of just a C++ standard library implementation, but from other libraries and sources.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, there is a boost-library implementation linked by the cppreference page. What I need is slightly different from computing Laguerre polynomials. I'm hoping that Visual Studio is currently using the fastest algorithm, and then I can just change their code to get what I want.

Comment: If you look in "crt\src\stl\special_math.cpp" you will find that it is just calling `boost::math::laguerre`. (Found with `grep -rin laguerre`.)

Comment: why don't you write the fastest implementation and share it with us

Comment: @rioV8 if this is it, it looks kind of complicated: https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/crandall/papers/Laguerre-f.pdf . I'm trying to save time. Of course, if I do eventually code it up, it will be available on GitHub.

Comment: the `cmath` version is about real valued arguments, the article you link is about **complex** valued arguments, a generalization of the real valued problem and adds complexity in the calculation

Comment: depending on for which values of `n` you need the result you can implement a specific version of the equation